# Upper bound on the singular values of the square root of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, singular-values

It is well known (see [Upper bound for the sum of absolute values of the eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1472420/upper-bound-for-the-sum-of-absolute-values-of-the-eigenvalues)) that for a matrix $A=(a_{ij})\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n s_i(A)\leq\sum_{i,j=1}^n |a_{ij}|,
$$
where $s_i(A)$ denote the singular values of $A$. I am now wondering whether the following generalization
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{s_i(A)}\leq\sum_{i,j=1}^n \sqrt{|a_{ij}|}
$$
still holds true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the assertion is true. To see this let $A=U|A|$ be a polar decomposition of $A$ and denote its $i$-th column by $a_i$. Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{s_i(A)}=\operatorname{tr}(|A|^{1/2})=\operatorname{tr}[(U^TA)^{1/2}]=\sum_{i=1}^n (U^TA)^{1/2}(i,i)\leq \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{(U^TA)(i,i)},
$$
where the last step used Peierls-Jensen's inequality. Since $U$ is orthogonal, we infer
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{(U^TA)(i,i)}\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\|Ua_i\|_2}=\sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\|a_i\|_2}\leq \sum_{i=1}^n\sqrt{\|a_i\|_1}.
$$
The proof is finished by using the elementary inequality $\sqrt{a+b}\leq\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$, $a,b\geq 0$, for $n-1$ times.