# lower bound for the trace$(A^\dagger A).$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Let $A$ be $n\times n$ complex squared matrix. I want to find a lower bound for $\mathrm{tr}(A^\dagger A).$ What I could find so far is that if $A$ is Hermitian then $$\mathrm{tr}(A^\dagger A) \geq \frac{|\mathrm{tr}(A)|^2}{\mathrm{rank}(A)}.$$
I wonder whether this is correct for non-Hermitian case.
Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify in your question the meaning of the symbol $A^\dagger$. In older literature on linear algebra, $A^\dagger$ usually means Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, whereas in physics literature, $A^\dagger$ usually means Hermitian transpose.

Comment: I meant Hermitian transpose.

Answer (score 1):

Your bound is indeed correct in general. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381808/sum-of-eigenvalues-and-singular-values) question (with say the top answer) shows that the sum of the singular values is at least the sum of absolute values of the eigenvalues.

On the other hand, a rank-$r$ matrix has exactly $r$ nonzero singular values $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_r$. Since the trace of $A^TA$ is the sum of the squares of the singular values, the quadratic mean-arithmetic mean and triangle inequalities give us 
$$\text{tr}(A^TA) = \sigma_1^2 + \ldots + \sigma_r^2 \geq \frac{1}{r}(\sigma_1+\ldots+\sigma_r)^2 \geq \frac{1}{r}|\text{tr}A|^2$$
as wanted.